# Vacuum expectation value for 2 point fermionic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I was trying to compute $\langle 0|T(\psi_\alpha(x)\bar\psi_\beta(y))|0 \rangle$, i.e., the 2-point function for the Dirac field. While, I could easily compute, $\langle 0|\psi_\alpha(x)\bar\psi_\beta(y)|0 \rangle$, but while computing, $\langle 0|\bar\psi_\beta(y)\psi_\alpha(x)|0 \rangle$, I couldn't proceed.

What I did:

$\psi_\alpha(x)=\sum_s\int\frac{d^3k}{(2k^0(2\pi)^3)^{\frac12}}(a(\vec k,s)u_\alpha(k,s)\exp(-ik\cdot x)) + b^\dagger(\vec k, s)v_\alpha(k,s)\exp(ik\cdot x))$

$\bar\psi_\alpha(x)=\sum_s\int\frac{d^3k}{(2k^0(2\pi)^3)^{\frac12}}(a^\dagger(\vec k,s)\bar u_\alpha(k,s)\exp(ik\cdot x)) + b(\vec k, s)\bar v_\alpha(k,s)\exp(-ik\cdot x))$

$\langle0|\psi_\alpha(x)\bar\psi_\beta(y)|0\rangle=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32k^0}(k\!\!\!/ + m)_{\alpha\beta}\exp(-ik\cdot (x-y))$, which is the result as expected.

But when I try to compute, $\langle0|\bar\psi_\beta(y)\psi_\alpha(x)|0\rangle=\sum_s\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32k^0}\bar v_\beta(k,s)v_\alpha(k,s)\exp(ik\cdot(x-y))$, which is wrong!

Now my question, where am I going wrong, as I should have got the factor, $\sum_s v_\alpha(k,s)\bar v_\beta(k,s)=(k\!\!\!/-m)_{\alpha\beta}$.

P.S. $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum of the field.